# Most efficient way of a list (or collection) item knowing about it's parent list?

Tags: c#, list, collections

Often with lists and the items inside them, I find the need to query or find things in the list the object has been added to.

For example:

```
// create list of levels
IList<Levels> levels = new List<Levels>
{
    levels.Add(new Level{ Depth = 1, Name = "Level 1" });
    levels.Add(new Level{ Depth = 2, Name = "Level 2" });
}

foreach(Level level in levels)
{
    bool lowestLevel = false;

    // would the lowest level be best worked out from a function that takes the list and the level?
    lowestLevel = Level.GetLowest(Levels, level);

    // as a calculated property of level itself where the level knows about the list of levels it's in?
    lowestLevel = Level.IsLowest;

    // or worked out when creating the level?
    // levels.Add(new Level{ Depth = 1, Name = "Level 1", IsLowest = isLowest });
    lowestLevel = Level.IsLowest;
}
```

Are any of these a 'best practice' way to handle something like this or is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote this directly in the text editor, apologies for any syntax errors.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you need an item in a list to "know" about the list containing it, or simply need to find an item _in_ a list according to some criteria?

Comment: Also - What do you mean by efficient way? Coding wise? Performance?

Comment: When the list of levels is being used, something outside of the levels may want to know (for example in a loop) if the current level falls at a particular place in the list.  For logic like this, do you ask the level (in the list) about that or have something externally that takes the list and the level and keeps the logic separate?

Comment: Performance mainly, would having a reference to a list in the item be poor practice?

Comment: Some other valid questions: can the levels be added to multiple lists? Can the levels in a list change during its life-time? Can their depth change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that adding to the collection being iterated over throws an exception...

There is definitely another way. When a `Level` needs to know about its siblings, you should encapsulate `levels` inside a class, say `LevelCollection`. You can give each `Level` a reference to its *parent* collection when you insert a level into a collection, and stop passing `levels` in the methods than need the siblings.

Comment: This is kind of what came to mind, but the IsLowest(level) is a method on the LevelCollection which encapsulates the linq result.  I thought about having a reference to the list of levels against each level, but alarm bells started to ring.

Comment: In this case you would store a reference to the lowest level as part of the `LevelCollection` and compare references for `IsLowest(level)`. When you add or remove a `Level` from the `LevelCollection` you could update those references.

Comment: @PhilCooper If you let `Level` objects reference their sibling collection, `IsLowest` would become a property of the `Level`, which would call `parent.GetIsLowest(this)` to obtain the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why now use Linq:

```
lowest = list.Max(x => x.Level);
highest = list.Min(x => x.Level);
```

Note that some of the Linq methods are not available if your list is of type IList. Also if you want to get the actual object (Level) then you have to use something like:

```
var lowest = list.OrderBy(x => x.Level).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is select proper structure for proper task. List is very common structure and do not have any special functionality.

So for this case you should have some structure where, when you add element it should decide where to put it. The whole graph theory will be very helpful for you to choose proper solution. If you find such structure, then you have to check that is was already implemented. The .NET Framework contain lot of common structure that might be helpful.

So instead of [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) you could use the [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx), and your Level class should implement the [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) interface.

The whenever you add the Level instance to such list, the Lowest level would be under index 0 of table (or size -1, this depend of the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) you will use)

A nice article about [Data Structure in C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364091%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do not store the `Depth` on the `Level` type. Instead pass a reference to the collection.
`Level.Parent = this;` in your `List.Add` method. You can always get the Depth by List.IndexOf(Level). This way, you won't need to update the Depth to all members everytime you change the collection.

```
public class Level
{
    public IList<Level> Parent { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LevelCollection : Collection<Level>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Level item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.Parent = this;
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        this[index].Parent = null;
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }
}
```

Then you can just query the parent to get the depth of item from within the level.

```
this.Parent.IndexOf(this);
```